# React component without extend React Component class

Tags: reactjs

I see in some source code, the author wrote a component like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Login = () => (
  <div>
    <h4>Hello World</h4>
  </div>
);

export default Login;
```

The thing I don't know is:

1. How react understand this is a react component by only using import
2. How can I add another callback method, such as `viewDidMount` ... I have added in code block but it compiles fail.

thanks

Comment: don't know the answer of **how react understand its a react component?**, but its called as `Stateless Functional Component` and used when you want to create a component that doesn't have any `state` or `lifecycle methods` means purely used to return a UI. check the `stackoverflow DOC` on `Stateless Functional Component`: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/reactjs/6588/stateless-functional-components#t=20170430073841125841

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is functional stateless component. It is for simple components.

You also can add component property types like this:

```
export const Login = () => (
  <div>
    <h4>Hello World</h4>
  </div>
);

Login.propTypes = {
  username: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

You can add callback like this:

```
// this place to define callback is more effective 
const onClick = e => (...)

const Login = props => {
  // or define here if you need access to props in onClick
  const onClick = e => (...)

  return <button onClick={onClick}>Submit</button>
}
```

Comment: he is asking **How react understand this is a react component ?** you are telling the benefits and properties of stateless functional component.

Comment: The react developers or someone who make deep analize react code may answer carefully. I think that react see if such function return react component so that finction is react component too.

Answer (score 2):

React "knows" that the code you wrote is a React Component because of transpilation. Transpilation is a process that occurs during build time where your code is changed from the code you wrote into something else.

In the case of React and JSX, your code turns into

```
export const Login = () => (
  React.createElement('div', {},
    React.createElement('h4', {}, 'Hello World')
  );
);
```

The angle brackets (`<`) are syntactic sugar for `React.createElement` and people use the angle brackets because they are simpler to use and type.